# How to get some pictures of a movie?

Tags: python, image, video, imdb, imdbpy

I am trying to get some pictures of a movie. I am currently using imdb module (Python: IMDbpy). I don't know how to get these images with the name of the movie or its IMDB id.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried this to check what info you can get on a movie based on its id ?

```
from imdb import Cinemagoer
imdb = Cinemagoer()

movie = imdb.get_movie('000000')

print(sorted(movie.keys()))
```

Comment: Yes, I did. I tried this too: 

ia= imdb.Cinemagoer()
mv= ia.search_movie("Matrix")
mv[0].get("photo sites")

But almost movie has no attribute "photo sites"

Answer (score 0):

If you do

```
mv[0].keys()
```

You will get every information that is available.
For instance

```
ia.get_movie('0133093').keys()
```

gives you 66 possible information.
https://imdbpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/usage/s3.html
Based on the docs and the IMDb database I'm not sure you can get pictures...